# Permitting moving only of <img>s within contentEditable <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, contenteditable

I am struggling to achieve my desired behaviour with a `div` marked as `contentEditable`. I wish to allow the user to move an `img` around within the `div` and for it to be maintained inline, but not let them resize or otherwise modify that `img`. They should otherwise be able modify the text within the `div`.

The default browser behaviour may be seen below, with the `img` being able to be both moved and resized with the drag-handles:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
      Here is some text, and also an <img src="http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/1747/imagead.png" /> image
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have been playing around with various client scripts to attempt to achieve the desired functionality, but each combination I attempt seems to run into difficulty. What I *can* achieve is ultimate lockdown with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img', '#edit').each(function (i, item) {
      item.contentEditable = false;
      $(item).bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      if ($.browser.msie) {
        item.oncontrolselect = function () { return false; }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

but although this prevents any element duplication (a problem I had in Firefox) and resizing using drag handles (in IE), it is not possible to move the `img` at all.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to you guys, the closest I have got so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img', '#edit').each(function (i, item) {
      attachEvents(item);
    });

    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
      document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, false);
    }
  });

  function attachEvents(item) {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
      item.attachEvent('onresizestart', function (e) { 
        e.returnValue = false; 
      }, false);
      item.attachEvent('ondragend', function (e) { 
        // cannot get IE to rebind moved item (toElement or similar is not available until IE9 when using addEventListener)
        attachEvents(e.srcElement);
      }, false);
    } 
    if ($.browser.opera) {
      // doesn't seem to work at all in Opera 11
    }
  }
</script>
```

but the two remaining problems are complete lack of support in Opera (something I can live with) and the problem of how to rebind the events `ondragend` in IE.

Can anyone else assist?

Comment: You might want to tag this kind of thing as "javascript" as well as jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a draggable effect using [JQuery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) on you `img`.

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers (notably Firefox but not IE), you can disable resize handles using `document.execCommand()` with the `enableObjectResizing` command:

```
document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", null, false);
```