# Disable resize for image in contenteditable div

Tags: html, dom, contenteditable

I want to make a simple editor for my website.

```
<div contenteditable="true">edfedasd</div>
```

its work, But i want disable resize for image in this div.

```
<div contenteditable="true">edfed<img src="/sm/1.gif">asd</div>
```

I test onmousedown,onmouseup,onselect,onfocus events But i can not do this!!!

Please help me!

Comment: I have not tried it but can you not just add `contenteditable="false"` to the `img` tag?

Comment: I test this, But do not work! :(

Comment: Then my next idea would be to move it out of the `<div contenteditable="true">` and user `css` or `js` to make it look like it is in the `<div>`... or can you wrap the image in a 2nd `<div contenteditable="false">`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864047/ie-how-to-disable-elements-selection-and-resizing-in-contenteditable-div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795132/permitting-moving-only-of-imgs-within-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Answer! I force image width and height by css.(min-max width-height) Its Work! Image not resize, But image width and height attribute will change! Not problem! We can remove attributes by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Set contenteditable="false" on the image

Comment: However, this also prevents the image from being deleted (e.g. by backspace).